# How do I create a column with the time in the previous column + a certain amount of time, only if that time has been entered?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to create a spreadsheet where I enter the time on a row and the next column over gives me the time plus 5 minutes. But I don't want it for every row, I only want it if there is some time entered.

This is what I've come up with:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", B2+TIME(0, 5, 0)) //for one cell   
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B), "", B2:B+TIME(0, 5, 0))) //attempt at entire column
```

And this only works somewhat. The first command works perfectly fine for one row, but if I enter it into the array formula, it returns a number between 0-1.

```
12:16:01 PM 0.5145949074
11:23:49 PM 0.9783448032
1:16:24 AM  0.05652777778
5:16:44 PM  0.7234259259
```

How do I make it so that the formula works for the entire column, without having to manually do it?

Comment: This may be due to the number format. Highlight the decimal cells -> format -> number -> time.

Answer (score 0):

ISBLANK() formula returns false when it detects any content in a cell. Even if there is a formula that generates no output.

[image]

You can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="", "", B2:B+TIME(0, 5, 0)))
```